# Storing Exceptions

Tags: python

When I tried to store the object of any exception. and raise it whenever I needed, instead of creating the object and then raising it.

Example:

```
import logging
a = IndexError("Just for testing")

for _ in range(6):
    try:
        raise a
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e, exc_info=True)
        logging.warning("\n\n")
```

part of the code is where

```
ERROR:root:Just for testing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-395d9b05bd40>", line 7, in <module>
    raise a
IndexError: Just for testing
WARNING:root:


ERROR:root:Just for testing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-395d9b05bd40>", line 7, in <module>
    raise a
  File "<ipython-input-5-395d9b05bd40>", line 7, in <module>
    raise a
IndexError: Just for testing
WARNING:root:


ERROR:root:Just for testing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-395d9b05bd40>", line 7, in <module>
    raise a
  File "<ipython-input-5-395d9b05bd40>", line 7, in <module>
    raise a
  File "<ipython-input-5-395d9b05bd40>", line 7, in <module>
    raise a
IndexError: Just for testing
WARNING:root:


ERROR:root:Just for testing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-395d9b05bd40>", line 7, in <module>
    raise a
  File "<ipython-input-5-395d9b05bd40>", line 7, in <module>
    raise a
  File "<ipython-input-5-395d9b05bd40>", line 7, in <module>
    raise a
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
IndexError: Just for testing
WARNING:root:
....
```

As you can see there are some **repetitions of the traceback**. Is it possible to clear its stack?

I am extremely Sorry if this seems lame.

Comment: There are repetitions because the code is repetitively raising the same exception in a loop (and ignoring it after logging its occurence). To detect that, you might be able to compare the current exception to the last (or a whole stack of them).

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping it was possible to clear that stack. So we can just view the stack

Comment: I don't know what stack you're talking about. I was suggesting that you create your own (since there isn't a preexisting one that I know about).